# Sufficient criterion for a binary string to have dense orbit

Tags: dynamical-systems, real-numbers, binary, approximation-theory

I was recently asked the following question: Does the map $$\mu : [0, 1) \rightarrow [0, 1)\\ \hspace{105px}x \hspace{5px}\rightarrow \hspace{5px}2x  \mod 1$$
have some point, say $\alpha$, whose orbit is dense in $[0, 1)$?

Once you consider representing $x$ as a binary string the solution comes fairly quickly, as $\mu$ can be seen to be just a shift to the left by one (dumping the digit past the decimal point.) I.e. $\mu(0.1010) = 0.010$

It follows that the number defined by concatenating all finite binary strings, $\alpha = 0.01000110110000…$ has a dense orbit in [0, 1). Having gotten to this point, I thought this screamed for a polynomial inspired generalization that I couldn’t solve (nor could the problem giver).

By [Stone-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) polynomials are dense in $C[0, 1]$, but per [Muntz-Szasz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem) one does not need the entire family of monomials $\{1, x, x^2, … ,x^n, …\}$ to achieve density, and it suffices instead to just use any subset $\{1, x^{a_1}, x^{a_2}, … , x^{a_n}, …\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_i} = \infty$.

Likewise my solution to the problem clearly has a whole lot of redundancy: for any fixed integer $N$, I could for example concatenate just the strings of length greater than $N$, or more strongly just the strings whose length is a multiple of $N$. I was not however able to go any further.

The question if unfortunately a bit vague, but I’m looking for a more restrictive construction, perhaps in the spirit of Muntz-Szasz, of some point with a dense orbit under this map.

Comment: If $\xi = \frac{k}{2^n}, 0\le k < 2^n$ is a finite sequence of bits not occurring in $x$, then no other sequence of bits starting with $\xi$ can be within $x$ either. This means $\mu^m(x) \notin [\xi, \xi + 2^{-n})$ for any $m$. Thus $x$ has dense orbit if and only if it contains every finite sequence of bits. And since each such sequence has infinitely many extensions, that sequence must occur infinitely many times. So that same redundancy in your example will also occur in every other example.

Comment: I should have thought of that. Thank you!